# how to filter out some strings from a line?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get only the `clientid` and the `dstid` from the input String. Here is the code I tried:

```
String input = "User clientId=287372.Dstid=129 Some more text clientId=336263. Dstid=2451. This clientNum=120";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(clientId=)(\\d+)(Dstid=)(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

while (m.find()) {
  System.out.print("clint id : " + m.group(1));
  System.out.println("Dst id : " + m.group(2));
}

m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

But the output I am getting is:

> User clientId=287372.Dstid=129 here is some text clientId=336263. Dstid=2451. This clientNum=120

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following regex

```
(clientId=[0-9]+)[.\s]*(Dstid=[0-9]+)
```

make sure to escape \ when using it

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(clientId=[0-9]+)[.\\s]*(Dstid=[0-9]+)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "User clientId=287372.Dstid=129 Some more text clientId=336263. Dstid=2451. This clientNum=120";
String[] numbers = input.split("[^0-9]+");
for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
    if(numbers[i].length()!=0){
        if(i%2==0){
            System.out.println("Dstid: "+numbers[i]);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("clientId: "+numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a period into your regular expression between the two id's. Also, groups are determined by parentheses, so you'll want second and fourth groups. You'll also need to add a possible whitespace between the period & `Dstid`, since the latter match has a space between them.

```
String input = "User clientId=287372.Dstid=129 Some more text clientId=336263. Dstid=2451. This clientNum=120";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(clientId=)(\\d+).[\\s]?(Dstid=)(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

while (m.find()) {
  System.out.print("client id: " + m.group(2) + " & ");
  System.out.println("Dst id: " + m.group(4));
}

m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

Outputs:

```
client id: 287372 & Dst id: 129
client id: 336263 & Dst id: 2451
User clientId=287372.Dstid=129 Some more text clientId=336263. Dstid=2451. This clientNum=120
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur help. But again i am struck with another input: String input = "2014<>10.100.2.3<><189>date=2014-01-16,time=11:26:14,type=traffic,srcip=192.168.192.123,srcport=2072,dstip=10.180.1.105,dstport=206 ,policyid=196";
............
.....


  System.out.println("Srcport: " + m.group(2) + " & ");
  System.out.println("Dstport: " + m.group(4));
  
} 
but I am not getting any output.Is there a mistake in the regex or output lines "....group(4)); ??

Comment: That would depend upon your regex and what kind of groups you've used in it. Care to share more details?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be

```
"(clientId=)(\\d+)|(Dstid=)(\\d+)"
```

Matching `clientId` or `Dstid`

```
 String input = "User clientId=287372.Dstid=129 Some more text clientId=336263. Dstid=2451. This clientNum=120";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(clientId=)(\\d+)|(Dstid=)(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
//  System.out.println("Dst id : " + m.group(2));
}
```

Output:

```
clientId=287372
Dstid=129
clientId=336263
Dstid=2451
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scanner to do the desired job. Here is the sample code

```
    String input = "User clientId=287372.Dstid=129 Some more text clientId=336263. Dstid=2451. This clientNum=120. Some more text clientId=12345. Dstid=2421.";

    Scanner s = new Scanner(input);

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(clientId=)(\\d+).[ ]*(Dstid=)(\\d+)");
    while(s.findInLine(p)!=null) {
          MatchResult res = s.match();
          System.out.println("clint id : " +res.group(2));
          System.out.println("Dst id : " + res.group(4));
    }
    s.close();
```

Here is the output of this code.

```
clint id : 287372
Dst id : 129
clint id : 336263
Dst id : 2451
clint id : 12345
Dst id : 2421
```

Hope this helps.